# 404 Rest Route not found - when serving behind "proxy"

Tags: url-rewriting, rest-api

To avoid CORS and speed up my static site, I have made a "proxy" from my static site.

Basically, I can make a request to: `staticsite.com/wp-json/some-endpoint` and it fetch and return the response from `mywordpresssite.com/wp-json/some-endpoint` (pretty cool if you ask me). It works fine for almost all my endpoints, however, I have just discovered that it doesn't work with this package: https://github.com/CalderaWP/searchwp-api-route

When I go to: `staticsite.com/wp-json/swp_api/search?s=query` it correctly returns the data from  `mywordpresssite.com/wp-json/swp_api/search?s=query`,however it returns `"No route was found matching the URL and request method"`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or what I could do to avoid this issue. It seems specific to this plugin somehow, since all the other endpoints work fine.

If I visit the endpoint directly from `mywordpressiste.com` it works fine.

Comment: You’ve put “proxy” in quotes. How exactly is this implemented?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I use cloudflare workers. In the worker script I simply check if "wp-json" is present in the pathname. If it is, it makes a new fetch request towards the same URL, expect it changes the hostname to "mywordpresssite.com"